How to document function parameters' order in JSDoc?
I've got a function that uses the arguments object to accept parameters, like this:
function DoLog() {
    let level='info', content, logger='log';
    switch (arguments.length) {
        case 1:
            content = arguments[0];
            break;
        case 2:
            level = arguments[0];
            content = arguments[1];
            break;
        case 3:
            level = arguments[0];
            content = arguments[1];
            logger = arguments[2];
    }
    console[logger](`[${level}] ${content}`);
}

and I want to document it in JSDoc.
I could just write:
/**
 * logger with log level and logger function specified
 * @param {String=} [level=info] - level of this log
 * @param {String} [content] - log content
 * @param {String=} [logger=log] - function to log (in console[logger])
 */

But actually there is a certain order of these three parameters, which means that I can call this function in three different ways:

DoLog(content)
DoLog(level, content)
DoLog(level, content, logger)

How can I document that?
After searching the web I found How do I document functions that have multiple parameter order options in JsDoc? and the answer in it says

You can use the @also tag to provide multiple method signatures

However, I didn't find @also tag in JSDoc documentation, so it seems like an outdated answer. Therefore, I didn't find anything helpful.

One would usually add optional parameters to the end, like so: DoLog(content) / DoLog(content, level) / DoLog(content, level, logger) so the order is always the same (DoLog(content, [level], [logger])). Any reason for this weird behaviour?

Does this answer your question? JSDoc - JS overload functions/methods

@also does exist, but it's internal: https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/blob/9f7eb1399069377610bb2fd37dc862d03c0ad02e/packages/jsdoc-tag/lib/definitions/internal.js#L19-L34

Or pass in an object then you don't have to worry about the switch statement at all.

@Rafalon Yes, there is. The code I posted above is a simplified example to explain the question, and actually I've got lots of complicated functions with optional parameters in complex order (image something like CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()). I've even written a function parseArgs (code is here) to deal with parameters' orders.

@jonrsharpe maybe @overload or @also works, but is there any JSDoc officially supported method?

@Andy That's a good idea. In some cases, a function supports both passing an object with properties as arguments, and passing parameters one by one (with order). And, I want to document all of these:)
